# Count occurrences in one column when another column is equal to something

Tags: excel-formula

So I have 2 columns:  'Issue Type' and 'Status'.  I want to count the number of "Closed" in the 'Status' column when the associated 'Issue Type' is equal to "Bug".  Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new column.  In that column, create a formula that returns 1 if 'Issue Type' is "Bug" and 'Status' is "Closed".  Otherwise return 0.  Sum the column.

Example formula

```
=IF(AND(B2="closed",C2="bug"), 1, 0)
```

This assumes column B has Issue Type, column C has status, and the formula is in Column D

I tried this in Excel, not sure if that's what you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late, but this code will work

```
=countifs(A:A,"Bug", B:B, "Closed")
```

It will count only if the Issue Type in Column A is Bug and Status in column B is Closed.